# Test-FileCatalog always returns "unable to open catalog file"

Tags: windows, powershell

We have hundreds of driver files provided as part of driver packages.

They look like this (this is an nvidia driver)

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        14.12.2023     10:16          26790 nvhda.cat
-a----        14.12.2023     10:16          80431 nvhda.inf
-a----        14.12.2023     10:16         129000 nvhda64v.sys
-a----        14.12.2023     10:16          41984 nvhdap64.dll
```

For each single *cat* one I've been calling

```
Test-FileCatalog nvhda.cat
```

and for each of those I got

`Unable to open catalog file <fullpath>\nvhda.cat`

The file permissions and owner are correct on all files. I've checked that the `cat` file is loaded via Sysinternals procmon, no issue with that.

I am on windows 10, but windows 11 also fails to produce anything. Also tested on windows server 2012.

When I create an empty catalog file with `New-CatalogFile` it works, but not on the external ones.

I can click onto the `cat` file and see the hash

[image]

Any hint would be much appreciated!

Here is my execution of it:

```
PS D:\> Test-FileCatalog -CatalogFilePath D:\nvhda.inf_amd64_1946e5c46f80c770\nvhda.cat -Path D:\nvhda.inf_amd64_1946e5c46f80c770\
Test-FileCatalog : Die Katalogdatei "D:\nvhda.inf_amd64_1946e5c46f80c770\nvhda.cat" konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ Test-FileCatalog -CatalogFilePath D:\nvhda.inf_amd64_1946e5c46f80c770 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Test-FileCatalog], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnableToOpenCatalogFile,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestFileCatalogCommand
```

Comment: What is Test-FilePath? I can find only Test-Path in the documentation.

Comment: @harrymc thanks for pointing my typo out. The topic mentions `Get-FileCatalog` but I mistyped it in the text :/

Comment: So is this still a valid question? Or do you need to update it?

Comment: @spikey_richie totally valid. The type was in the thread, not in my local repro code. `Test-FileCatalog` fails for basically all cat files for me.

Answer (score 0):

I get exactly the same results :
"Test-FileCatalog : Unable to open catalog file".

The
[Test-FileCatalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/test-filecatalog?view=powershell-7.4)
commands is described as:

> Test-FileCatalog validates the authenticity of files by comparing the file hashes of a catalog file (.cat) with the hashes of actual files on disk.

It seems like it needs write-access to the folder in order to compute
the hash, meaning that it writes first the hashes to the folder
and only after compares them. This is a logical conclusion, since
this command is also intended to work on entire folders and not only
on single files.

Comment: I've tested it on directories I own, so I am not sure what is happening. Process Monitor should also report an invalid access to the file, when requested mode is `write`. Did you make it work?

Comment: Are you using it the way it's described in the documentation, with `-CatalogFilePath` and `-Path`, to compare one against the other? Please include your exact command in the post. Note: I don't have test files to compare myself.

Comment: From the directory I was in: ` Test-FileCatalog -CatalogFilePath .\nvhda.cat -Path .` . I also tried absolute paths. Same result.

Comment: I'm not sure that (1) It accepts relative paths, (2) It can compare a file against itself. Is the current folder `C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository`?

Comment: I've edited my question to add the example call. My current folder is not FileRepository. I assumed it must be the directory where the cat referenced files are?

Comment: My understanding of this tool: The `.cat` file has driver files lying around. Often in the same directory. The cat files has hashes of all those files in its vicinity. I assume that `Test-FileCatalog` reads the cat and its hashes, and uses the `-Path` to verify that the hashes match the files (which it hashes). At the end it also does `Get-Authenticode` on it self, but this is not important to me.

Comment: I think you have proved that it doesn't work this way.